# Apple Connect API financialReport Returning 403 The resource 'financeReports' does not allow 'CREATE'. Allowed operations are: GET_COLLECTION"

Tags: ios, curl

Trying to pull financial reports from apple connect api and getting a 403 for CREATE operation, this is not documented :/. anyone know how I use a GET_COLLECTIONS operations here with cURL?

```
exec("curl -v -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer {$token}' \"https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports\" -d 'regionCode=Americas&reportDate=2020-01&reportType=FINANCIAL&vendorNumber=xxx&' -o output");
```

Response:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "bb9e260c-c3d4-4df9-b78e-f34dfd42c449",
    "status" : "403",
    "code" : "FORBIDDEN_ERROR",
    "title" : "The given operation is not allowed",
    "detail" : "The resource 'financeReports' does not allow 'CREATE'. Allowed operations are: GET_COLLECTION"
  } ]
}
```

[response][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3dcv.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GET, Not POST

```
exec("curl -v X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer {$token}' \"https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?regionCode=Americas&reportDate=2020-01&reportType=FINANCIAL&vendorNumber=xxx\" -o output");
```

should do the trick!